# distinct records with inner join in oracle joins

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I am using following query to return a list of records:

```
Select DISTINCT A.Id Questionid,
  A.Created_Date Questiondate,
  Row_Number() Over ( Order By A.Created_Date Desc) Row_Id,
 B.Id Answerid,
 COUNT(*) OVER (partition by a.id) QCOUNT,
 B.Created_Date Answerdate
From Question_Table A
Inner Join Answers_Table B
ON A.Id      =  B.Question_Id
AND A.Is_Active = 1
AND A.Is_Delete = 0
And B.Is_Active = 1
And B.Is_Delete = 0 
And A.Category_Id = 1318221772
```

Answers_Table.question_id is mapped to question_table.id

Hence, for a particular question id, there can be more than one rows on answers_table.

The Output now displaying is:

QUESTIONID    QUESTIONDATE  ROW_ID     ANSWERID QCOUNT ANSWERDATE

```
52776   08-DEC-12   1   31383   2   09-DEC-12
52776   08-DEC-12   2   31482   2   10-DEC-12
52719   07-DEC-12   3   31321   1   07-DEC-12
```

But my requirement to display output as:

QUESTIONID    QUESTIONDATE  ROW_ID     ANSWERID QCOUNT ANSWERDATE

```
52776   08-DEC-12   1   31383   2   09-DEC-12
52719   07-DEC-12   3   31321   1   07-DEC-12
```

How can I display unique questionid (like 52776,52719) on to the output?

Comment: Do you still want three rows, but for the question data to not appear on non-first rows?

Comment: I want only to display rows having unique question id.

Comment: Show us in the question what you want the output to be, as well as what it is now.

Comment: So you only want to see the earliest answer?

Comment: yes this is my requirement...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do you may be able to rewrite this with a Group By statement.  However, if you want to keep your existing query, try changing this line:

```
  Row_Number() Over (Order By A.Created_Date Desc) Row_Id,
```

to this:

```
  Row_Number() Over ( partition by a.id Order By B.Created_Date ASC) Row_Id,
```

And then make the whole thing a subquery selecting where row_id = 1.  This should just return one row per Question and only the earliest Answer for that Question.

```
Select * From (
Select DISTINCT A.Id Questionid,
  A.Created_Date Questiondate,
  Row_Number() Over ( partition by a.id Order By B.Created_Date ASC) Row_Id,
 B.Id Answerid,
 COUNT(*) OVER (partition by a.id) QCOUNT,
 B.Created_Date Answerdate
From Question_Table A
Inner Join Answers_Table B
ON A.Id      =  B.Question_Id
AND A.Is_Active = 1
AND A.Is_Delete = 0
And B.Is_Active = 1
And B.Is_Delete = 0 
And A.Category_Id = 1318221772
) Where ROW_ID = 1
```